# Sql Group By Two Fields

Tags: sql, pivot

I have two tables `Customers` and `CustomerStatusEntries` :

```
CustomerStatusEntries
---------------------------
Id | Branch | CustomerStatus_Value | Customer_Id

CustomerStatus_Value  = ("B" = "Block" , "E" = "Created" etc...)
```

I need to get this output

[image]

Comment: Wich RDBMS? Please post both table structures and sample data, it will help a lot to get some answers and not lot of -1's

Comment: You need to `PIVOT`. If you reveal what kind of SQL you're using, someone might tell you how. Or you can search.

Comment: am using SQL Server i stated the fields that the users need to help me out... i think one can easily conclude that customer table has an id which is the primary key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Branch AS 'Branch Code',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Created',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Active',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Blocked',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cancelled',
    COUNT(CustomerStatus_Value) AS 'All'
FROM CustomerStatusEntries
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: +1 but still missing the `Total` row, also it seemns the `Id` is not present and `Branch` alias is `Branch Code`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fixed number of columns you've shown in your sample, you could do this:

```
SELECT Branch, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Created,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blocked,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerStatus_Value = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancelled,
       COUNT(*) AS All
    FROM CustomerStatusEntries
    GROUP BY Branch;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with standard SQL:

```
select branch_code,
       sum(case when CustomerStatus_Value = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as Created,
       sum(case when CustomerStatus_Value = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Blocked,
       ...
from t
group by branch_code
order by 1
```